# Resolve "localhost unexpectedly closed connection" error in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working through "Mean Machine: A beginner’s practical guide to the JavaScript stack" by Chris Sevilleja. My problem is on page 60. Per the book's instructions, I have created a small server.js file, along with the package.json, and used npm install to create the node_modules folder and populate it with the appropriate modules. When I run 'server.js', I receive a message in the terminal running the console.log() message that I placed at the end of the program. So I know the program ran. But when I then go to Chrome and put 'https://localhost:8080" in the search bar, I receive the following error message:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I have spent over an hour trying to figure this out and am pretty lost. If I use 'http' instead of 'https', it just takes forever to load (I waited for 5 minutes). I have checked whether I have asynchronous DNS flag in Chrome or something and confirmed that it is enabled. I tried doing "$ lsof -i:8080" on the terminal and got:

> COMMAND  PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE > NAME
>   node    6188    23u  IPv6 0x3a96cd0448d7ba87      0t0  TCP > *:http-alt (LISTEN)

(Not really sure what it does but I saw it on a webpage addressing a similar problem and the responders instructed the person to do that.) I have tried accessing it on Safari as well and receive the same message.

My code is below:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set the port for our app

var app = express(); // define our app in terms of Express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json);

// configure out app to handle CORS requests
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization');
    next();
});

// log all requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// API routes

// basic route for the home page
// route, not middleware, so no 'next' parameter
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to the home page!');
});

// get an instance of the express router
var apiRouter = express.Router();

// test route to make sure everything is working
// accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api
apiRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({message: 'Welcome to our API.'});
});

// mount apiRouter on our app
// they will all be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// start the server on the port we indicated on line 6
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Any suggestions for getting my 'res.send('Welcome to the home page!');' message to display would be fantastic. Thanks in advance. I've tried to describe the problem as well as I can but if there is any other information you need please let me know.

Sort of a follow up: I'm using SublimeText. Is this problem something I could identify/solve using a more sophisticated IDE?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console after you start your app?

Comment: Did you confirm that the program is still running when you make the request?

Answer (score 1):

Change your port and then try it again

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8888;
```

http://localhost:8888

Answer (score 0):

I had a **docker container** running for another app, that **used the 4200 port**.
Shutting down that container solved the issue.